# Best pratice to update blank values to null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
| COL1      | COL2          | COL3      | COL4      | COL5  |
|---------- |-----------    |--------   |--------   |------ |
| 20170302  | 5693153.2     | 0         | 3.0665    |       |
| 20170301  | 0             | 3.061     |           |       |
| 20170301  | 0             | 3.064     |           |       |
| 20170302  | 0             | 3.0755    |           |       |
| 20170302  | 0             | 3.0755    |           |       |
| 20170302  | 0             | 3.0755    |           |       |
| 20170424  | 0             | 3.44      |           |       |
| 20170301  | 0             | 3.0645    |           |       |
```

You can see I got a lot of    ( Blank ) values. What would be the best way to update this ( lets say I have more than 100 columns ) to `null`?

I made a script on excel, with `update table  set col1 = null where col1=''` for all columns. But I'm curious to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

That is the only way really. You can potentially speed it up by checking if any of the columns are blank first with `WHERE col1='' OR col2='' OR ...` because that avoids updating rows that do not require changing (potentially reducing writes to the log and data files). The effect of this will be small or nothing if most of the rows have at least one blank that needs to be replaced though.

As a side note: should those columns be strings at all? The sample data suggests a numeric type of some variety would be more appropriate.